# Вести подсчет случайного появляения значения из массива

Tags: php, массивы, случайные-числа, for

Есть массив:
`$array = array('a','b','c','d','e');`

C помощью `array_rand` получаем случайный элемент из массива

`$rndvalue = $array[array_rand($array)];`

Как создать цикл, который бы вывел какой из случайных элементов массива был выведен 10 раз. Не больше.
То есть в результате, должно получиться что-то типо:

```
b - 10 
a - 5 
c - 7 
d - 8 
e - 1
```

Здесь - 10 раз выпало случайно значение *b* и на этом цикл завершился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
$resultArr = []; // or $resultArr = ['a' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'c' => 0, 'd' => 0, 'e' => 0];
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $resultArr[$array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)]] += 1;
}
print_r($resultArr);
```

З.Ы. Может выкинуть Notice, но отработает. Не любите нотисы - заглушите их: `(@$resultArr[$array[mt_ra..)` или заранее инициализируйте результирующий массив: `$resultArr = ['a' => 0,'b' => 0,'c' => 0,'d' => 0,'e' => 0];`

Comment: Не будет работать

Comment: ну как бы работает)

Comment: Работает но выкидывает предупреждение, что само по себе плохо. Совет заглушить нотисы на мой взгляд ужасен )) Уж лучше предотвратить их

Comment: Глушить/не глушить - зависит от задачи. В данном примере с массивом это не критично от слова ВААААЩЕ.

Comment: Согласен, но как мне кажется использовать `@` является bad practice. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь

Comment: Вообще не ошибаетесь. Зато теперь чел узнает шо за зверь такой -  @. :) Плюс я дополнил ответ вариантом.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте цикл, соберите все случайно сгенерированные элементы в промежуточный массив, и произведите подсчёт значений этого массива:

```
$array = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
$total = [];

while (! in_array(10, $total)) {
    $randValues[] = $array[array_rand($array)];
    $total = array_count_values($randValues);
}

var_dump($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Отобразит сколько раз выпал каждый элемент, в случае если элемент ни разу не выпал - значение будет 0.

```
$array = array('a','b','c','d','e');

$result = array_combine($array, array_fill(0,count($array), 0));
while (!in_array(10, $result)) {
    $key = $array[array_rand($array)];
    $result[$key]++;
}

var_dump($result);
```